# instantaneous rate of change from a graph

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Kyi.png)

Question: Determine the instantaneous rate of change of the volume of water remaining in the pool during at 1.5h.

I am confused because I tried to find the equation of the graph to solve this problem, but I couldn't. Can someone please guide me and show my how to find the solution to this question?

Comment: Your professor is a jerk, and/or has provided you with more information than you've given us.

Comment: I think we can solve this problem by drawing a tangent line to the graph. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BorKari I believe the issue is that we are only given discrete values to work with - no function that we could use the derivative of to find an exact equation of the tangent line

Comment: Are you sure that your instructor did not ask for an _approximation_ of the instantaneous rate of change, or the average rate of change over some interval? Or, did they perhaps indicate a particular model?

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the rate of change by calculating the slope of the tangent line to the curve at your desired point.

Answer (score 1):

Without an explicit function to work with, the best we can do is attempt to find an approximation to the tangent line at the specified point. Recall that a line passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$, where $m$ is the slope of the line. For a tangent line at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ of a function $y=f(x)$, the slope is $m=f’(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Now approximate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. Can you proceed?